# How to add div to datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, datatables

I would like to know whether it is possible to add a canvas to a datatable.

I have installed the datatable responsive plugin which, in case the column is too width, clicking a button will allow you to see extra information.

I would like to know whether I can add a canvas to the hidden area in order to play an audio which correspond to the selected row. I wish to use a nice audio player called [wavesurfer.js](http://www.wavesurfer.fm/)

To be able to do do that I need to learn the following:

- How to add a canvas at the end of the hidden area
- How to force the responsive table to not display the canvas in case the table has enough space
- The canvas has to fill the hidden div 100%

Picture of what I am trying to achieve (Each row is an audio file)

[image]
Please see the following for your information

```
<div id="demo">
   <div id="waveform">
      <div class="progress progress-striped active" id="progress-bar" style="display: none;">
         <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 100%;"></div>
      </div>
      <wave style="display: block; position: relative; -webkit-user-select: none; height: 128px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden;"><canvas width="870" height="128" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 870px;"></canvas><wave style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 0px; display: block; box-sizing: border-box; border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: 1px; border-right-color: navy;"><canvas width="870" height="128" style="width: 870px;"></canvas></wave></wave>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h26cxgc8/

Comment: Set display:none in canvas styling and u can save canvas data to database using canvas.toDataURL() which returns a base64 string which cn be stored into DB :)

Comment: Each row is an audio stored in a directory. The canvas is created by the wavesurfer.js. Let's put it in another way. How do you add a div using javascript where I put the player?

Comment: You mean each row represents an audio ?...Whats the use of canvas here??You can easily add a div by setting its innerHTML and appending it to the DOM :)

Comment: Getting there :) how can I do that, any example?

Comment: just found this: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: I doubt i still cant understand your problem sadly :(

Comment: How can I use this method if I am using `columnDefs` instead of `columns`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the format() method in the [child rows example provided in comments](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). You can modify format to return a div into which probably you can create a canvas using wavesurfer.js

```
function format(d) {
  return '<div class="player"></div>';
}
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "columns": [{
    "className": 'details-control',
    "orderable": false,
    "data": null,
    "defaultContent": '+'
  }, {
    "data": "Name"
  }, {
    "data": "Position"
  }, {
    "data": "ID"
  }]
});
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = table.row(tr);
  if (row.child.isShown()) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    // Open this row
    row.child(format(row.data())).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

Here is a demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/189Lp6u6/16/**

Comment: Yes, this is definitely what I want, I was reading the tutorial but for my specific table when I add `{
            "className": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": ''
          },` this will trigger a console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

Comment: you see that error because of `"columns"` option in `Datatable`. In my demo the table columns are different and you should define columns option as per your table structure.

Comment: The problem I have is that the responsive plugin conflicts with the format function. Please see this for your information https://jsfiddle.net/v1xnj3u4/

Comment: I get two + buttons and there is a clear conflict. When the table is enough large the div appears whereas it does not work when the responsiveness happens

Comment: Thank you for your help. you answered my question, I will ask another for this issue

Comment: get rid of the `+` in `defaultContent`. Then you won't see the two plus symbols. I am glad it helped

Comment: the problem is no the + but the format function. if I get rid of the + I still cannot open it if the table is too narrow