# How can I add another child to a responsive datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I add another(two) child(ren) to a **responsive** datatable.

If the table is too narrow and I click the + button this does nothing

Any thoughts on this?

```
function format ( d ) {
    return '<div class="player"></div>';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v1xnj3u4/

Comment: I've looked at the fiddle, what is the desired outcome?

Comment: I want to add the div at the end of the responsive area. Therefore, I need only one button. Please make sure you resize the table to make it very narrow. What I really need is the creation of a child even when the responsive plugin is activated

Comment: Ahh, that's a clever plugin. So if the table row is too short to show all the data the first cell gets a plus sign which, when clicked, drops down another cell into visibility with the cut off cells in? Brilliant! I guess that in order to get what you want you'd need to get into the plugin script and add to it. It seems as though, from looking at the source, you can alter the `renderer` function of the plugin, perhaps that's the best place to look?

Comment: any idea? https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.6/js/dataTables.responsive.js

Comment: Does not seem an easy thing to do :(

Comment: It seems that both Responsive extension and your child row details functionality conflict with each other for the use of child rows. You may want to use [custom renderer](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/custom-renderer.html) for the Responsive plug-in but that will only be displayed when table is too small.

Comment: I have 35 columns in the same table so the responsive plugin is a must. I wanted to add some audio to each row. The solution I was thinking was to add the audio tag at the end of the responsive child but this cannot be done apparently. I can put an event if I double click a row but this is my last option since I want to be able to play two audios at the same time. The custom render does not fix the problem if I use the responsive plugin

Comment: See my attempt at a solution, it doesn't do just as you ask as it doesn't create a second row, but it does add to the content of the created row. The trick is to add what you want to the data and using the `renderer` in this way means you don't have to hijack the existing plugin code. 

Please do forgive the creation of jQuery objects and then grabbing the `outerHTML` from them and leaving them in limbo... but I do like that way of creating objects and without getting the `outerHTML` property you'd just end up with a couple of [Object object]s.

Comment: @annoyingmouse your solution is brilliant but if the button + disappears it will make the div invisible and the only option I have to see it is is to resize the browser window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work though it doesn't create another row as such but just adds to the created row the div you specified:

```
"responsive": {
    "details": {
        "renderer": function ( api, rowIdx ) {
            // Select hidden columns for the given row
            var data = api.cells(rowIdx, ':hidden').eq(0).map(function(cell){
                var header = $(api.column(cell.column).header());
                return $("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>",{
                    "text": header.text()+':'
                })).append($("<td></td>",{
                    "text": api.cell( cell ).data()
                })).prop('outerHTML');
            }).toArray().join('');
            return data ?
                $('<table/>').append( data ).prop('outerHTML') + $("<div></div>", {"class":"player"}).prop('outerHTML') :
                false;
        }
    }
},
```

Working example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/dud3wrvg/), thanks for the challenge, I enjoyed learning about that ;-)

Comment: This is my preferred solution. However, this does not work when the table is not compressed because the + button disappear

Comment: If that's the case I think that you're better off using a different solution rather than the responsive plugin. In your original JSFiddle, when you compressed the table the green icons became visible and your render on the first cell meant that sometimes the icon was visible in the child row.

Comment: Can I force somehow the responsive button to stay there even when the table is not compressed

Comment: Nope, I don't think so, not without digging into the underlying plugin code and then it's probably not a good idea as you'll likely get better results doing something else. This looks like it'd work for you: https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: This is the one I used in my jsfiddle above :( Can I open the child clicking on the row somehow?

Comment: So it's the responsive plugin that's causing the problems...? Have a look at the JSFiddle I'm working on now:https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/0w2ygpyp/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31135234/2511306 This is what I am trying to achieve without disabling the responsiveness of the table. You are very close to the solution I believe and to be honest I am not very good at javascript

Comment: Not sure it's trivially easy to combine the two I'm afraid. Sorry not to be of more help. Back to work now I'm afraid. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make (+) icon stay all the time if you make one of the columns hidden, you can create a dummy column for that purpose and use one of the Responsive plugin [special classes](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes#Special-classes) `none` as `'className: 'none'` for that dummy column.

In the example below I used last column for that purpose because in the row details it will also be displayed last.

Then when enumerating the columns in [custom renderer](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/custom-renderer.html) you can display what you want for that column if that special column header matches some predetermined value (I used `'Extra 10'` which is the header of the last column).

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28m3q10b/1/) for demonstration.

PS: I used [excellent answer and example by @annoyingmouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31141915/3549014) as a base for this answer so my vote goes to him as well.

Comment: Ahh, thank you @Gyrocode.com I didn't clock the `"className": "none"` option